# Frame animation doesnt work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uianimation

```
viewDidLoad :

topBarMenu = [[TopBarMenu alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:topBarMenu];
    topBarMenu.clipsToBounds = YES;


- (void)menuButton_TouchUpInside:(TopBarIcon *)sender
{
    isTopBarMenuShown = !isTopBarMenuShown;

    if (isTopBarMenuShown) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 600);
                                }];
    }else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 0);
              }];
    }
}
```

In my code i want to animate showing and hiding my menu. Showing is very stepped and dosen't look nice. Hiding immediately remove the screen without any animation. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **set constant**  when you are using Autolayout and Animation. So, set constant before you begin the Animation. So, create outlet of constrain of  y position.

```
topbaryposition.constant=0; (IBOutlet of Top position (Y postion of Topbar))


- (void)menuButton_TouchUpInside:(TopBarIcon *)sender
{
    isTopBarMenuShown = !isTopBarMenuShown;

    if (isTopBarMenuShown) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 600);
                                }];
    }else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 0);
              }];
    }
}
```

Something like ,

**Edit :-**

I found your Issue .

Your issue is seeting the frame in else when you hiding the topbar.you have set only height as **0** but you also need to set **y positioan as 0**..

Something like ,

```
topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 0);




- (void)menuButton_TouchUpInside:(TopBarIcon *)sender
{
    isTopBarMenuShown = !isTopBarMenuShown;

    if (isTopBarMenuShown) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 600);
                                }];
    }else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 0);
              }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't solve my problem.
Ehh. Found solution , i added [self.view layoutIfNeeded] and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if (sideView.frame.origin.x >= 0 )
    {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            sideView.frame=CGRectMake(-400, 45, CGRectGetWidth(sideView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sideView.frame));
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }

    else
    {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            sideView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 45, CGRectGetWidth(sideView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sideView.frame));
        } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {

         }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think set frame directly is not a very good method,I suggest to change frame is more appropriate.
Such as:

```
- (void)menuButton_TouchUpInside:(TopBarIcon *)sender
{
    isTopBarMenuShown = !isTopBarMenuShown;

    if (isTopBarMenuShown) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            CGRect rect = topBarMenu.frame;
            rect.size.height = 600.0f;
            topBarMenu.frame = rect;
            //topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 600);
                                }];
    } else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
            CGRect rect = topBarMenu.frame;
            rect.size.height = 0.0f;
            topBarMenu.frame = rect;
            //topBarMenu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 1024, 0);
              }];
    }
}
```